# Wamp Apache - Allow localhost

Tags: apache, wamp, httpd.conf

There are other questions similar to this but don't answer my problem.

This is the default `httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

and it allows only `127.0.0.1`, but I want to allow also `localhost` and `192.168.x.x` (my private ip).

Well, the other answers are: put `Allow from all` and uncomment in `hosts` file the line `127.0.0.1 localhost`; but I read that is unsecure or not reccomended.

So I've tried this:

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from 192.168.x.x
    Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```

It works for `192.168.x.x`, but not for `localhost` (gets error: *403 Forbidden, You don't have permission to access / on this server.*)

1) How can make it works?

2) Maybe is required to uncomment in `hosts` file the line `127.0.0.1 localhost` ?

3) Is it really more secure than Allow from all?

Answer (score 9):

Lets keep it simple, try this

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1 localhost 192.168 
</Directory>
```

::1 is the IPV6 equivalent of 127.0.0.1

I would use the first 3 of the quartiles 192.168.0 ( assuming your third quartile is 0 )

Answer (score 3):

Update your `httpd.conf` to this, and you will be able to get to `localhost` on WAMP.

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from 192.168.x.x

    Allow from ::1
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 
Apache 2.4
then use:

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
    Require all denied
    Require ip 127.0.0.1 
    <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'localhost'">
    Require all granted
    </If>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't know if your Directory sintax is correct as I use ubuntu server, but I always put the lines that allow individual addresses **before** the "Deny from all" directive. However, in the apache documentation you can see examples where the directives are in the same order as in your code

[Link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order)

I alse specify the netmask, which in the case of individual IPs should be 255.255.255.255, more fine-grained subnet restriction.

I have always seen the words deny,allow in the first directive in lowercase, but as you are using Windows maybe it is not necessary. The code that I would use is:

```
order deny,allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255
Allow from 192.168.x.x/255.255.255.255
Allow from localhost/255.255.255.255
Deny from all
```

2) Yes, as you are denying every petition except those  that come from the specified IPs

[Related reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow)

Comment: Tried your code but there's something wrong because Apache is not able to restarting.

Comment: Did you execute the whole code? I mean your first 4 lines, then my code, then the </Directory>

Comment: yes, I've replaced my last 5 lines (before </Directory>) with your code. Currently I make it works uncommenting the line `127.0.0.1 localhost` in `hosts` file, but I don't know if it's good.